# Sharing UIViewController instance between TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift

is it possible to share a UIViewController instance between UITabBarController buttons, I have a very simple app that you can swap between 'Playstation' and 'Xbox' buttons and the only change is the images in the tableview.

I want to make sure that both Views always look the same, so if someone is searching for something, the search query would be the same & the tableview scroll position etc.

Something so when the user presses the Xbox button it'd just call a 'reloadData()' on the tableView and it'd check if the selectedIndex == 0 or 1 and set-up the cells based on that.

Here's my current app to give you an idea

[image: Playstation Version]

[image]

Comment: Actually every `ViewController` embedded inside a `UITabBarController` can access it and vice versa. You should share your code related to the problem.

Comment: One thing you can do is to match the scroll positions of both controllers either by broadcasting via `NotificationCenter` or something else. Sharing the controllers is not doable.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740291/having-trouble-adding-a-view-as-a-subview-to-multiple-view-iphone-dev

Comment: You should also take a look at RxSwift, it allows you to make subscriptions from one VC to another, and you may achieve your goal by using that.